# Error to make SQLite command in C# using variables?

Tags: c#, sql

I have problem in C# to make a SQLite command. I've trying to use code like this:

```
SQLiteCommand komenda = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT cena FROM dniowka WHERE (model = '@Name' AND element = '@Name2')", cnn);
```

but it doesn't work... :( before i used LIKE statement:

```
SQLiteCommand komenda = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT cena FROM dniowka WHERE model LIKE @Name AND element LIKE @Name2", cnn);
```

it works. But I have a little problem. When I have a few records that contain "AL" for example, "1AL, 2AL, AL ...". I do not know how to do to get the only one record "AL" (@ Name2 = AL).

Does anyone have any idea?

[P. S. sorry for my english ..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't need to use apostrof when you using *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*.

Use parameters in your query like `model = @Name` not `model = '@Name'`

The right usage of this;

```
SQLiteCommand komenda = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT cena FROM dniowka 
                            WHERE model = @Name 
                            AND element = @Name2", cnn);

komenda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
komenda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name2", Name2);
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of LIKE you can use =

e.g.

```
"SELECT cena FROM dniowka WHERE model = @Name AND element = @Name2"
```

Note that I didn't include single quotes:

'@Name'  <-- BAD

@Name <-- GOOD